# Increasing the bounty for an answer I have already given a bounty

Tags: support, bounty

I had indicated a bounty of 50 points for an outstanding answer. I wanted to increase the amount to 100 points, but it seems that the 50 was locked in.

So after waiting the requisite 24 hours, I went to award the additional 50 points. A pop-up indicated that I could irrevocably give 100 bounty points.

Please forgive my confusion: does that mean 100 cumulative points (my initial 50 plus 50 more) or 100 additional?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

[The rule is](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/bounty)

> if you offer multiple bounties on the same question, the minimum spend doubles with each subsequent bounty (50 reputation on the first bounty, 100 reputation on the second, 200 on the third, and so on).

Which means 100 additional points.

Comment: Thanks. My apologies to some extent as this showed up as asked previously. I must have missed it. I will delete my question in a minute after you have seen my message.

Comment: Good explanation. An additional detail, strictly the next bounty size must be only at least the minimum of twice the former and 500, which is the maximal bounty size).

Comment: @quid Darn, guess +1000 bounties aren't a thing? :P